# drools input validation and stop execution

Tags: validation, drools

I have to validate some elements for null and then stop execution if they are null.

I have few rules like below which checks for some null values and adds errors

```
rule "Require begin date for Service Period"
    salience 100 
    when
        $servicePeriod : ServicePeriod(beginDate == null)
        // check this to avoid the infinite loop
        eval(!$servicePeriod.getValidationErrors().contains("Begin date is required."))
    then
        $servicePeriod.getValidationErrors().add("Begin date is required.");update($servicePeriod);
end
```

I have some rules like below which first checks 'validationErrors.size() == 0'. Even though validation errors size is greater than zero, it continues to check other validation and fails as they are null. Please let me know how I can modify these rules to avoid exception.

```
// Rules for Firefighter deduction calculation
rule "Firefighter Annual Salary Deposit Calculation"
    salience 50 
    when
        $servicePeriod : ServicePeriod(validationErrors.size() == 0 , periodType.name == "DEPOSIT" , payType.name == "ANNUAL SALARY" , serviceType.name == "FIREFIGHTER" )
    then
        calculateDeduction($servicePeriod, 0.075);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you're thinking that in Java, such constraints are evaluated from left to right, so if the first constraint checks for 0 or null, then further constraints are safe. However, this is not the case in Drools comma-separated constraints.

I think that you might be able to switch to a more Java-style expression:

```
ServicePeriod(
    validationErrors.size() == 0, 
    periodType != null && periodType.name == "DEPOSIT", 
    payType != null && payType.name == "ANNUAL SALARY", 
    serviceType != null && serviceType.name == "FIREFIGHTER" )
```

I'm not totally sure without testing though.